How to change a url into corsproxy url?
"http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt&q="
I want to change this url to cors proxy url (want to bypass cors issue) otherwise I am getting CORS error while running the application. It is working fine if I use CORS extension but if it is deployed for any user it should work.
